# Alphabet Triangle in C

Tags: c, loops, char

I have struggled for hours and still cannot figure out this problem.
Below is the answer I found from net:

```
int main(){  
  int ch=65;    
    int i,j,k,m;    
  system("cls");  
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)    
    {    
        for(j=5;j>=i;j--)    
            printf(" ");    
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)    
            printf("%c",ch++);    
            ch--;    
        for(m=1;m<i;m++)    
            printf("%c",--ch);    
        printf("\n");    
        ch=65;    
    }    
return 0;  
}
```

Below is the code I try to do the same thing:

```
int main(void){
  char ch;
  int i, j, k, m;
  printf("Please Enter a capital character: ");
  while(scanf("%c", &ch) == 1){
    for (i = 0; i < (ch - 'A' + 1); i++)
    { 
      for (j = (ch - 'A' + 1); j > i; j--)
        printf(" ");
      for (k = 'A'; k < ch; ++k)
        printf("%c", ch);
      for (m = ch; m > 'A'; m--)
        printf("%c", m);
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Try another one(q to quit): ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to make the program more interactive, and the answer just go weird, what should I revise to make it work properly?
Is there any better idea about coding this same program?

The Answer should be:

```
     A
    ABA
   ABCBA
  ABCDCBA
 ABCDEDCBA
```

My code:

```
   CCCB
  CCCB
 CCCB
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function is very complicated for no reason.

```
void print(int rows)
{
    for(int row = 1; row <= rows;row++)
    {
        int ch;
        for(int space = row; space < rows; space++) printf(" ");
        for(ch = 0; ch < row; ch++) printf("%c", 'A' + ch);
        while(--ch) printf("%c", 'A' + ch - 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printTpLetter(char ch)
{
    print(ch - 'A' + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    printTpLetter('E');
    print(3);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b7nhfo

1. Use functions for this kind of tasks.
2. Try to write the generic function

Comment: Thank you!, I did revise my code as you say, and the logic is much more clear now. I was trying to combine all of the tasks together, and as a result, my program became very complex.